# wpa_supplicant wifi-direct connection between Linux and Android

Tags: wifi, android, wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

I'm trying to make wifi-direct connection between Android and Linux. I'm using rtl8188au.

I found some tips about wifi direct by using wpa_supplicant, so I get wpa_supplicant v2.0. and this is what I did for wifi-direct.

```
1.Compiled rtl8288au driver, activated nl80211.
2.Compiled wpa_supplicant and wpa_cli for nl80211.
3.Run wpa_supplicant on linux, with option -Dnl80211. success.
4.Set ip address for wlan0.
5.Run wpa_cli, and try to connect to android device.
```

The connection can made success at once, but disconnected soon.

Here is wpa_cli logs.

**wpa_cli -p /var/run/wpa_supplicant**

```
> p2p_find
OK
<3>P2P-DEVICE-FOUND e6:fa:ed:8a:5e:e8 p2p_dev_addr=e6:fa:ed:8a:5e:e8 
pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='[Phone] Kulong' config_methods=0x188 
dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x0
>
>
> p2p_connect e6:fa:ed:8a:5e:e8 pbc
OK
<3>P2P-FIND-STOPPED
<3>P2P-DEVICE-FOUND e6:fa:ed:8a:5e:e8 p2p_dev_addr=e6:fa:ed:8a:5e:e8 
pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='[Phone] Kulong' config_methods=0x80 
dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x8
<3>P2P-GO-NEG-SUCCESS
<3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=
<3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 38:1d:d9:d4:db:70 completed (auth) 
[id=0 id_str=]
<3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=9 BSSID=38:1d:d9:d4:db:70 SSID=DIRECT-4J
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED e6:fa:ed:8a:de:e8
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=14122 method=254
<3>WPS-REG-SUCCESS e6:fa:ed:8a:de:e8 2d96823c-8a30-5dd0-a267-e3adae8b1564
<3>P2P-GROUP-FORMATION-SUCCESS
<3>P2P-GROUP-STARTED wlan0 GO ssid="DIRECT-4J" freq=2412 
passphrase="xZbKV6sF" go_dev_addr=38:1d:d9:d4:db:70
<3>WPS-SUCCESS
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE e6:fa:ed:8a:de:e8
<3>AP-STA-CONNECTED e6:fa:ed:8a:de:e8 p2p_dev_addr=e6:fa:ed:8a:5e:e8
<3>AP-STA-DISCONNECTED e6:fa:ed:8a:de:e8 p2p_dev_addr=e6:fa:ed:8a:5e:e8
<3>P2P-DEVICE-LOST p2p_dev_addr=e6:fa:ed:8a:5e:e8
```

Is there anything wrong?

If so, what should I do for complete wifi-direct connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs not only wpa_supplicant but also iwpriv, hostapd, dhcpd.

here is what I did for wifi-direct connect.

**Device Mode ( Linux requests connection to Android)**

```
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.15 up
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set enable=0
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get status
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get role
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set enable=1
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set intent=1
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get status
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set op_ch=6
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set ssid=DIRECT-RT
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set setDN="RTL8192CU"
iwlist wlan0 scan
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get2 wpsCM=<MAC_ADDRESS_OF_TARGET_DEVICE>
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get2 devN=<MAC_ADDRESS_OF_TARGET_DEVICE>
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set prov_disc=<MAC_ADDRESS_OF_TARGET_DEVICE>
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set got_wpsinfo=3
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set nego=<MAC_ADDRESS_OF_TARGET_DEVICE>
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c ./wpa_0_8.conf -B
wpa_cli wps_pbc <MAC_ADDRESS_OF_TARGET_DEVICE>
```

**GO Mode ( Android requests connection to Linux)**

```
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set enable=3
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get status 
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get role 
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set intent=1
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set op_ch=6
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set ssid=DIRECT-RT
./hostapd -B ./p2p_hostapd.conf
<<<<< Request connection from Android >>>>
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get peer_deva
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get req_cm
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_set got_wpsinfo=3
iwpriv wlan0 p2p_get peer_ifa
./hostapd_cli wps_pbc any
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.254
dhcpd
```

But there's some necessary conditions for wifi-direct connection.

1. Your wireless driver should support nl80211.
2. Configure 'nl80211' option when MAKE wpa_supplicant, hostapd.
3. dhcpd configuration files.(dhcpd.conf, dhcpd.lease)
4. wpa_supplicant, hostapd configurations( conf files )

I hope this article may be useful for who wants wifi-direct between Linux and Android.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yet, what is the content of `wpa_0_8.conf`?

Comment: Unfortunately iwpriv and iwlist are not available in Fedora 38.